Unity3D VR Third Person Controller Animation
Good morning,
I'm programming a game on Unity VR using an asset called Starter Assets - ThirdPerson and with animation from Mixamo.
Unity animator transition
I am endeavoring to ensure that when a player with Layer 'Player' enters the Sphere Collider, they will be tracked using the animations with the IsRunning settings, but it is not working correctly.

using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;
    public LayerMask playerLayer;

    private Transform player;
    private Animator _animator;
    private bool isChasing = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        _animator = transform.parent.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isChasing)
        {
            Vector3 direction = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;
            transform.position += direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            _animator.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("IsRunning", false);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if ((playerLayer.value & (1 << other.gameObject.layer)) > 0)
        {
            isChasing = true;
            player = other.transform;
            Debug.Log("Player entered the detection zone");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if ((playerLayer.value & (1 << other.gameObject.layer)) > 0)
        {
            isChasing = false;
            Debug.Log("Player exited the detection zone");
        }
    }
}

Inspector Unity
I'm working on a Meta Quest Pro 3 on the Oculus system. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Add logs to the root of OnTrigger events, before layer check. And also output the collider info, e.g. game object name, so you know what collision it is. If these logs show that the collision is happening, your problem is layers. Otherwise your problem is collision, in which case 1) check that at least one of your colliders (logically this has to be your chacracter) has a rigidbody, 2) open Project Settings > Physics and play with the “Contact Pairs Mode” setting, starting with “Enable All Contact Pairs”.` I think kinematic-static might work, as character is likely kinematic.
